# which is more powerful from statistical point of view?

Tags: regression, logistic, correlation, multivariate-analysis, quantiles

If you study a correlation between two continuous variables and you find significant statistical correlation in univariate correlation analysis and you want to know weather this association was independent or not so you proceeded to multivariate analysis.

Which is more powerful statistically to do multivariate linear regression analysis or to convert the dependent variable to categorical variable e.g, by dividing it into tertiles or quartiles and to do multiple logistic regression.

If you did not find significant correlation in multivariate analysis weather linear or logistic, does this means there is no real association between these variables?

If significant association was found, does this means the explanatory variable is a cause for the outcome variable or it is just association and needs another way to find there is a causal relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Say $X$ and $Y$ are your variables.

The end goal will be to determine whether there exists a function $f$ satisfying $f(X) = Y$ to some degree of accuracy.

Linear regression could possibly yield the function $f$, but it is not likely due to the fact that $f$ is restricted to be linear.

You should instead consider methods for non-linear regression.

You mention dividing the variables into tertiles or quartiles and attempting logistic regression.  This approach attempts to reach the same goal, but the relationship in the end will be weaker.  It is recommended to try this if non-linear regression works poorly.